# Qt how to change to C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, qt-creator, qmake

I couldn't perform `#include <variant>` in Qt 5.14. I've tried to change the .pro file by adding `CONFIG += c++17` or `CONFIG += c++1z warn_on` or `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++17` but none of them work.

Any fix to this?

Comment: If i didn't misremember it, Qt is now trying to be basd on C++ 17, but has not finished yet.

Comment: @John Ding so how can i include new templates such as variant?

Comment: Perhaps move all C++17 code to a separate cpp file. Not sure if the compiler will produce ABI-compatible code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik • _Not sure if the compiler will produce ABI-compatible code_  lol, that's a good one!

Comment: What is your compiler? Those switches work for me. Additionally, I use `strict_c++` to use the C++ standard, instead of gnu++, which is the default.

Comment: This will be compiler dependent.  If you are using Visual Studio's compiler it will be  `/std:c++17`  When you build your code either QtCreator or the command line should show you the compiler params and output.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, there's been plenty of bugs with QtCreator where "build clean" didn't suffice in picking up changes to the .pro file.  Ultimately, you may want to "build clean" followed by completely removing the "build-" folder in the parent folder where the object code gets generated.  Project settings get cached there too.

Comment: @selbie I tried everything still didnt work. However, when compiling in the command line, this doesnt throws me an error regarding "variant" ```g++ *.cc -o output```, but this throws: ```g++ -std=c++17 *.cc -o output```

Comment: What throws?  You probably need to show your code and provide an [mcve] if you want to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that my Qt doesnt recognize variant module is because it is run by gcc-5. So I updated gcc and g++ to version 7:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt update
sudo apt install g++-7 -y
```

This is to update the symbolic links to version 7

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 60 \
                         --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7 
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
gcc --version
g++ --version
```